# Jenkins: How to get value from a Groovy Script to be used in a downstream project?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I need to be able to get some slave information to be used in one of my jobs.

I have a Groovy system script to access the slave information

```
for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {
  println('====================');
  println('Name: ' + aSlave.name);
  println('getLabelString: ' + aSlave.getLabelString());

  ... In here I can dig out the information that I need
}
```

Is there a way how I can get the information back to use in a Post Build Job?

I need to add the output to a parameter or something that can be used by a Post Build Job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used The EnjEnv plugin and it has a 'Evaludated Groovy Script' section that basically you can do anything... but it should return a property map that will be used as Environment variables. I don't know how to return a value from a Groovy script so this worked kewl for me as I can reference property (or Environment variables) from almost anyware

```
import hudson.model.*

String labelIWantServersOf = TheLabelUsedOnTheElasticAxisPlugin; // This is the label assosiated with nodes for which i want the server names of
String serverList = '';

for (aSlave in hudson.model.Hudson.instance.slaves) {          
  out.println('Evaluating Server(' + aSlave.name + ') with label = ' + aSlave.getLabelString());  

  if (aSlave.getLabelString().indexOf(labelIWantServersOf ) > -1) {
    serverList += aSlave.name + ' ';        
    out.println('Valid server found: ' + aSlave.name);                  
  }    

}

out.println('Final server list where SOAP projects will run on = ' + serverList + ' which will be used in the environment envInject map');

Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>(2);
myMap.put("serverNamesToExecuteSoapProjectOn", serverList );
return myMap;
```

And then I write the environment variable serverNamesToExecuteSoapProjectOn to a property file using a windows batch script and pass the property file to the next build as a parameterized build

Answer (score 1):

If you are running windows I have got a solution for you: You can save your settings into environment varables, which are usable for the currently running job. They will no longer exist once the job is finished, but they are usable for post-build action. Here is an example:

```
//Creating String to make my example more clear
String myString = 'this is just a test!';

//Create an environment variable, so the Jenkins job can use the parameter  
def pa = new ParametersAction([new StringParameterValue('PARAMETER_NAME', myString)]);  

// Add variable to current jobs environment variables.
Thread.currentThread().executable.addAction(pa) 
println 'Script finished! \n';
```

After the script ran you can use %PARAMETER_NAME% (if post-build-actions etc.) to gain access to its content.

Additional Hint: To see all available environment variables you can use the build step "execute windows batch command" and click on "See the list of available environment variables" on the buttom (the variables you create while executing scripts are excluded). But you can use these variables within your groovy script using e.g.:

`String jenkinsHome = System.getenv('JENKINS_HOME');`

Comment: no problem. Please don't forget to accept the answer so other users can use it too ;)